# DateFormat showing wrong output for weekday in flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, datetime-format

I was searching on web for similar issue like in below link

[github issue link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65726)

Here the person closed the issue ,and i can't find similar problem anywhere else.

In my case i am making horizontal calendar like below
[image]

This is the current week but here for 6th jan it is showing sunday which in reality is wednesday and i am also using DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime(................))

so i think resolving above issue will solve my issue too.

Mycode:

```
"${DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime(appState.date.year, appState.date.month,currentWeek[index].weekday)).substring(0, 1)}",
```

where current week is

[2020-12-28 13:55:50.903787, 2020-12-29 13:55:50.903787, 2020-12-30 13:55:50.903787, 2020-12-31 13:55:50.903787, 2021-01-01 13:55:50.903787, 2021-01-02 13:55:50.903787, 2021-01-03 13:55:50.903787, 2021-01-04 13:55:50.903787, 2021-01-05 13:55:50.903787, 2021-01-06 13:55:50.903787, 2021-01-07 13:55:50.903787, 2021-01-08 13:55:50.903787, 2021-01-09 13:55:50.903787, 2021-01-10 13:55:50.903787]

which seems correct to me. This list contain data of current and previous week

Edited:

```
class MyInheritedWidget extends InheritedWidget {

  final DateTime date;
  final List<DateTime> bothWeek;
  final DateTime currentdate;
  final DateTime currentWeekFirstDay;
  final DateTime currentWeekLastDay;
  final DateTime previousWeekFirstDay;
  final DateTime previousWeekLastDay;
  final int selectedDay;
  final int monthDateCount;
  final bool isDateHolderActive;
  final Map<int, bool> dayAvailabilityMap;
  final ValueChanged<bool> toggleDateHolderActive;
  final ValueChanged<int> setSelectedDay;

  MyInheritedWidget({
    Key key,
    this.date,
    this.currentdate,
    this.bothWeek,
    this.currentWeekLastDay,
    this.currentWeekFirstDay,
    this.previousWeekFirstDay,
    this.previousWeekLastDay,
    this.selectedDay,
    this.monthDateCount,
    this.isDateHolderActive,
    this.dayAvailabilityMap,
    this.toggleDateHolderActive,
    this.setSelectedDay,
    Widget child,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(MyInheritedWidget oldWidget) {
    return oldWidget.selectedDay != selectedDay ||
        oldWidget.toggleDateHolderActive != toggleDateHolderActive;
  }
}

class DateIndicatorPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            DateIndicator(),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class DateIndicator extends StatefulWidget {
  static MyInheritedWidget of(BuildContext context) => context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType();

  @override
  _DateIndicatorState createState() => _DateIndicatorState();
}

class _DateIndicatorState extends State<DateIndicator> {
  DateTime date = DateTime.now();
  DateTime currentdate=DateTime.now();
  List<DateTime> bothWeek=[];
  DateTime currentWeekFirstDay;
  DateTime currentWeekLastDay;
  DateTime previousWeekFirstDay;
  DateTime previousWeekLastDay;
  int selectedDay = 1;
  int monthDateCount = 1;
  bool isDateHolderActive = false;
  bool _isButtonDisabled;

  void toggleDateHolderActive(bool flag) {
    setState(() {
      isDateHolderActive = flag;
    });
  }

  void setSelectedDay(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedDay = index;
    });
  }

  DateTime findFirstDateOfTheWeek(DateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime.subtract(Duration(days: dateTime.weekday - 1));
  }

  DateTime findLastDateOfTheWeek(DateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime.add(Duration(days: DateTime.daysPerWeek - dateTime.weekday));
  }

  DateTime findFirstDateOfPreviousWeek(DateTime dateTime) {
    final DateTime sameWeekDayOfLastWeek =
    dateTime.subtract(const Duration(days: 7));
    return findFirstDateOfTheWeek(sameWeekDayOfLastWeek);
  }

  DateTime findLastDateOfPreviousWeek(DateTime dateTime) {
    final DateTime sameWeekDayOfLastWeek =
    dateTime.subtract(const Duration(days: 7));
    return findLastDateOfTheWeek(sameWeekDayOfLastWeek);
  }

  void getDaysInBetweenBothWeek(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= endDate.difference(startDate).inDays; i++) {
      bothWeek.add(startDate.add(Duration(days: i)));
    }
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    _isButtonDisabled=false;
    final DateTime dateForValues =DateTime(date.year, date.month+1, 0);
    monthDateCount = dateForValues.day;
    print("month $monthDateCount");

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    currentWeekFirstDay=findFirstDateOfTheWeek(currentdate);
    currentWeekLastDay=findLastDateOfTheWeek(currentdate);
    previousWeekFirstDay=findFirstDateOfPreviousWeek(currentdate);
    previousWeekLastDay=findLastDateOfPreviousWeek(currentdate);
    getDaysInBetweenBothWeek(previousWeekFirstDay, currentWeekLastDay);
    print("dates $bothWeek");

    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 150),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          IconButton(
            icon:Icon(Icons.chevron_right),
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 68.0,
            padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(left: 7.0, right: 3.0, top: 2.0, bottom: 2.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.blueAccent.withOpacity(.7),
                    offset: Offset(0.0, .5),
                    blurRadius: 3.0,
                    spreadRadius: 0.3),
              ],
            ),
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: 14,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return MyInheritedWidget(
                      date: date,
                      currentWeekFirstDay: currentWeekFirstDay,
                      currentWeekLastDay: currentWeekLastDay,
                      previousWeekFirstDay: previousWeekFirstDay,
                      previousWeekLastDay: previousWeekLastDay,
                      currentdate: currentdate,
                      selectedDay: selectedDay,
                      bothWeek: bothWeek,
                      monthDateCount: monthDateCount,
                      isDateHolderActive: isDateHolderActive,
                      toggleDateHolderActive: toggleDateHolderActive,
                      setSelectedDay: setSelectedDay,
                      child: DateHolder(index,currentdate,date,currentWeekLastDay,currentWeekFirstDay,bothWeek,previousWeekFirstDay,previousWeekLastDay));
                }),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon:Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
            color: Colors.black,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DateHolder extends StatelessWidget {
  static MyInheritedWidget of(BuildContext context) => context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType();

  DateHolder(this.index,this.currentdate,this.date,this.currentWeekLastDay,this.currentWeekFirstDay,this.bothWeek,this.previousWeekFirstDay,this.previousWeekLastDay);

  final int index;
  final DateTime currentWeekFirstDay;
  final List<DateTime> bothWeek;
  final DateTime currentWeekLastDay;
  final DateTime previousWeekFirstDay;
  final DateTime previousWeekLastDay;
  final DateTime date;
  final DateTime currentdate;

  final Widget activeBubble = Container(
    width: 15.0,
    height: 15.0,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      shape: BoxShape.circle,
      color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isSelectedDate = date.compareTo(currentdate) == 0;
    final appState = DateIndicator.of(context);
    print("current week days:${bothWeek[index].weekday}");

    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        appState.toggleDateHolderActive(true);
        appState.setSelectedDay(index);
        print("Date $index selected!");
      },
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                  child: Text(

                    ///? TO CHECK

                    "${DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime(appState.date.year, appState.date.month,bothWeek[index].weekday)).substring(0, 1)}",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: 12.0),
                  )),
              Container(
                width: 45.0,
                height: 45.0,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: !isSelectedDate? Colors.orange:Colors.white,
                  border: (index == (appState.selectedDay) &&
                      appState.isDateHolderActive == true)
                      ? Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)
                      : Border.all(color: Colors.transparent),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "${bothWeek[index].day}", // to avoid showing zero
                      style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: 16.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          (appState.dayAvailabilityMap[index] ?? false)
              ? Positioned(right: 8.0, bottom: 5.0, child: activeBubble)
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2021-12-28 was monday. I think your problem is related to the numbers you're showing below the weekdays initial letter, because these are correct according to the dates you described

Comment: how can resolve it because current week list is correct???????

Comment: I think it will be necessary to take a look at your code to check it out

Comment: I have inserted the whole code, here current week has been changed to bothWeek