# dateformat showing wrong text output for weekday in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, date-format

I'm facing a problem, as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65593793/dateformat-showing-wrong-output-for-weekday-in-flutter), but there is no answer.

first of all my code with int values, where the result ist correct:

```
List<int> listeWeekday() {
  List<int> gesamteWeekdays = [];
  String date;
  for (int d = 1; d <= dateMonth; d++) {
    if (d < 10) {
      date = wochenTag.format('yyyy-MM-0$d');
    } else {
      date = wochenTag.format('yyyy-MM-$d');
    }
    DateTime dateTimeObject = DateTime.parse(date);
    var dateTimeOWeekday = dateTimeObject.weekday;
    gesamteWeekdays.add(dateTimeOWeekday
        );
  }
  return gesamteWeekdays;
}
```

result:

```
I/flutter (17056): Inhalt der Liste weekday:[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1]
```

(the month ist February, so the quantity of days and the number of the weekday ist correct)

Now the problem. When I try to convert the number of the weekday into text it doesn't work properly:

```
List<String> listeWeekday() {
  List<String> gesamteWeekdays = [];
  String date;
  for (int d = 1; d <= dateMonth; d++) {
    if (d < 10) {
      date = wochenTag.format('yyyy-MM-0$d');
    } else {
      date = wochenTag.format('yyyy-MM-$d');
    }
    DateTime dateTimeObject = DateTime.parse(date);
    var dateTimeOWeekday = dateTimeObject.weekday;
    var dateTimeOweekdayEEE =
    DateFormat('E', 'de_DE').format(DateTime(dateTimeOWeekday));
    gesamteWeekdays.add(
        dateTimeOweekdayEEE,
        );
  }
  return gesamteWeekdays;
}
```

result:

```
I/flutter (17056): Inhalt der Liste weekday:[Di, Mi, Do, Sa, So, Mo, Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Sa, So, Mo, Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Sa, So, Mo, Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Sa, So, Mo, Mo]
```

in the result there ist no Friday, but the Monday two times (in the locale en-us there is the same issue, so the german locale is not the problem).

Does anybody have an idea how to resolve this problem?
Thank you very much,

Best regards
Patrick

Comment: Your code does not compile.  Please provide a minimal, *reproducible* example that demonstrates the problem you're observing.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're doing wrong.   You're making exactly the same mistake as https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/309 and as https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/344: You're constructing `DateTime(dateTimeObject.weekday)`, but the first argument to `DateTime` is a *year*, so you're computing dates for January 1 of years 1, 2, 3, etc.